# Dynamically update a select box depending on JSON data with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am quite new to AngularJS and have the following problem: I have two select boxes which I fill with data that is stored in an external JSON file. I want to dynamically fill the second box depending on the item that was selected in the first box. Every item in the first box has a key called relation. I want to use the value of this key as a trigger for dynamically updating the items available in the second box.

Can anyone help me on this? I have already tried to write a function but it doesn't work. Thanx in advance.
This is the JSON structure:

```
{
"filterElements": [
    {
        "parameters": [
            {
                "paraName": "paraOne",
                "relation": "default"
            },
            {
                "paraName": "paraTwo",
                "relation": "default"
            },
    {
                "paraName": "paraThree",
                "relation": "defaultshort"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "relations": [
            {
                "defaultrelation": 
        [
                    "equals",
                    "does not equal",
                    "greater than",
                    "less than"
                ]
            },
            {
                "defaultshort": 
        [
                    "equals",
                    "does not equal"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

[MyFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n7tgqbv5/)

Comment: what js have you tried / what does your controller look like?

Answer (score 0):

Based on you're fiddle, you're missing to bootstrap application. Example:

```
<body ng-app="list">
 ...
</body>
```

After that, you need to register ListCtrl to the existing application.

```
var app = angular.module('list',[]);

app.controller('ListCtrl', ListCtrl);

function ListCtrl($scope, $http) {
   ...
}
```

After doing this, you're controller will be executed, you're request will be made and you can bind the data to your view.

Comment: Hi there, sorry, maybe the explanation wasn't as clear as it should be. I uploaded the files on  [Plunker] (http://plnkr.co/edit/i3ZCi1r3R8LZuoVebeR2?p=preview) now, so you can actually see what I mean. My problem is that I want to fill the second drop down with items depending on the JSON data of the selected item in the first drop down. For instance: if the user selects paraThree, the second box shall be filled with equals and not equals only because the JSON key relation of paraThree has a defaultshort relation defined in JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. Here is the solution if anyone is interested:

```
$scope.change = function (paraSelection) {
$scope.filteredrelations = [];
for(var key in $scope.relations){
  if(angular.isDefined($scope.relations[key][paraSelection.relation])){
    $scope.filteredrelations = $scope.relations[key] paraSelection.relation];
        }
    }
};
```

Complete working example can be found here:
[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/oA8EeieaoEK0koTehELk)